# Does malloc(sizeof(x)) initialise the allocated memory with x?

Tags: c, malloc, sizeof

Does `tmp = malloc(sizeof(x));` the same automatically as `tmp = malloc(sizeof(x)); *tmp = x;`?

More specifically, is malloc instantly initialising my variable or is it just allocating memory and I have to initialise it myself?

Comment: That's not at all the case. There's nothing there that would make that happen. Also, `tmp = x` is likely wrong, you probably mean `*tmp = x`.

Comment: @Petra Enis,  What is `x`?

Comment: Use `ptr = malloc(sizeof ptr[0] * n);`

Comment: You _can_ get it zero-initialized if you want to though. See [`calloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator `sizeof` yields the size in bytes of its operand.

That is for example if the identifier `x` denotes a name of a variable of the type `int` then the expression `sizeof( x )` yields the value `4` provided that for objects of the type `int` the compiler reserves `4` bytes.

So this call

```
tmp = malloc(sizeof(x));
```

will be equivalent to the call

```
tmp = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

that in turn is equivalent to

```
tmp = malloc( 4 );
```

This statement just tries to allocate dynamically `4` bytes. The allocated memory is uninitialized.

Moreover the expression sizeof( x ) if `x` is not a variable length array is evaluated at compile time before the program begins its execution.

You could initialize it with zeroes the following way

```
tmp = calloc( 1, sizeof( x ) );
```

Answer (score 4):

No.

The memory returned by malloc isn't initialized.

Quoting [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc),

> Allocates size bytes of uninitialized storage.

Answer (score 4):

No. Even if `malloc` weren't *defined* to be uninitialized storage, `sizeof(x)` has *nothing* to do with the runtime value of `x` (it's just a friendly way to find the size of a variable's underlying type). There's no runtime use of the value of `x` *at all* in the code you provided.

Answer (score 0):

No, the function `malloc()` simply allocates memory on the heap. It doesn't initialize the pointer.

Comment: _"on the heap"_ sounds like an implementation detail that could vary even though it's probably true in most cases.